# How do I properly insert an XML document into another using rexml?

Tags: xml, ruby, rexml

I have managed to figure out the primary part of my question, "how do I insert one XML document into another?"  The result I get will work but the printed XML is missing a linefeed.

```
s = <<EOF
<application>
  <email>
    <host>mail.test.com</host>
    <port>25</port>
  </email>
</application>
EOF

p = <<EOF
<auth>
  <user>godber</user>
  <pass>foo</pass>
</auth>
EOF

subdoc = REXML::Document.new(p)
doc = REXML::Document.new(s)
doc.root.insert_after( '//email', subdoc.root )
doc.write
```

this outputs the following, which you can see has the auth tag starting immediately after the email close tag without a newline

```
<application>
  <email>
    <host>mail.test.com</host>
    <port>25</port>
  </email><auth>
  <user>godber</user>
  <pass>foo</pass>
</auth>
</application>
```

Actually, just as I have finished this I realized that I can change my last line to

```
doc.write( $stdout, 2 )
```

This was clearly written in the rexml tutorial, I had just overlooked it assuming that something else was wrong.  I guess I will submit this just in case anyone else is puzzled by this.  If anyone has tips along these lines, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 2):

REXML is doing exaclty what you are asking:  `doc.root.insert_after('//email', subdoc.root)` means put `subdoc.root` just after the last `email` element. And the last `email` element ends exactly after the `>` in `</email>`.

Whitespace nodes, although often overlooked by us human reader, cannot be ignored by XML parsers. 
The key thing here is this XML document

```
<doc>
  <email>
  </email>
</doc>
```

is not composed by an `email` element inside a `doc` element. In fact it is made of, in order,

- root `doc` element,
- one text node with the text "[newline][space][space]",
- an `email` element that contains a text node "[newline][space][space]",
- another text node with the text "[newline]".

This means that REXML cannot arbitrarily add the spaces needed to indent `auth` in the way we expect it.

A way to work around this is to ask REXML to force a re-serialization of the XML document, this is what you have done using the `#write` method with a positive indentation level. But you can do that only if whitespaces are not important in your document: would you let REXML reformat a snippet of carefully indented Ruby code?